# Which dictators has Trump had meetings with during his presidency?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, foreign-policy, dictatorship

Donald Trump [claims](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-52161529) he has to meet with "presidents, prime ministers, dictators, kings, queens – I don’t know, somehow I don’t see it [referring to wearing a face mask] for myself." Besides the safe claim that Kim Jong-un of North Korea is a dictator, which other dictators has Trump met with during his tenure as President?

Comment: Apart from William Henry Harrison, have there been any US presidents who haven’t met with dictators?

Answer (score 8):

It is quite hard to determine if the leader of a country can be classified as a dictator, so I've decided to define one as the ruler of a country classified by [Freedom House's 2018 report](https://freedomhouse.org/report/freedom-world/2018/democracy-crisis) as "Not Free".

Trump has met publicly and personally with the leaders of [Afghanistan](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/11/28/us/politics/trump-afghanistan.amp.html), [Azerbaijan](https://az.usembassy.gov/president-azerbaijan-ilham-aliyev-met-president-donald-trump/), [Bahrain](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/remarks-president-trump-crown-prince-salman-bahrain-bilateral-meeting/), [China](https://ft.com/content/889d837c-9712-49bf-9d97-2ed418f33f8b), [Egypt](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/remarks-president-trump-president-el-sisi-egypt-bilateral-meeting-new-york-ny/), [Iraq](https://www.al-monitor.com/pulse/originals/2020/01/iraq-president-barham-salih-davos-meeting-trump-restraint.html), [Khazakhstan](https://www.euractiv.com/section/central-asia/news/president-of-kazakhstan-meets-trump-ahead-of-key-un-appearance/), [Libya](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/readout-president-donald-j-trumps-meeting-prime-minister-fayez-al-sarraj-libya-2/), [North Korea](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/amp/ncna1025041), [Qatar](https://www.aljazeera.com/amp/news/2019/07/trump-warm-qatar-190710065719405.html), [Russia](https://www.npr.org/2019/06/28/737102340/president-trump-meets-with-russian-president-vladimir-putin-at-g20-summit), [Rwanda](https://ft.com/content/bc03253e-0282-11e8-9650-9c0ad2d7c5b5), [Saudi Arabia](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/03/20/us/politics/saudi-crown-prince-arrives-at-white-house-to-meet-with-trump.amp.html), [Somalia](https://allafrica.com/stories/201705221046.html), [Tajikistan](https://huffpost.com/us/entry/us_592535f8e4b0ec129d308cbe), [Thailand](https://www.voanews.com/east-asia-pacific/thailands-prime-minister-finds-common-ground-trump), [Turkey](https://www.politico.com/amp/news/2019/12/04/trump-erdogan-meet-nato-075188), the [United Arab Emirates](https://www.uae-embassy.org/news-media/sheikh-mohamed-bin-zayed-al-nahyan-meets-us-president-donald-trump), [Uzbekistan](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/05/16/world/asia/trump-uzbekistan.amp.html), [Venezuela](https://theguardian.com/world/2020/feb/05/donald-trump-juan-guaido-meeting-us-venezuela-measures) (as recognised by the US, not the current de facto President) and [Vietnam](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-northkorea-usa-vietnam-trong/trump-meets-vietnamese-president-before-second-north-korea-summit-idUSKCN1QG0CZ).

As far as I can tell, he has not met with the leaders of Algeria, Angola, Belarus, Brunei, Burundi, Cambodia, Cameroon, CAR, Chad, DRC, Republic of the Congo, Cuba, Djibouti, Equatorial Guinea, Eritrea, Ethiopia, Gabon, Iran, Mauritania, Oman, South Sudan, Sudan, Swaziland (eSwatini), Syria, Turkmenistan, Yemen, and Zimbabwe.

Obviously at international summits it is highly likely that Trump will have met with some of these leaders behind the scenes, but it is impossible for me to speculate about private meetings.

Comment: Well researched.   However I think that being a dictator relates to "a ruler with total power over a country", rather than success implementing the ideals of democracy.   Lets take Afghanistan for example, are you saying that Ashraf Ghani obtained or is is holding power by force?

Comment: Ghani faces serious power struggles with the Taliban, so he lacks total power.   And compared to that opposition, Ghani represents a republican form governance (by a constitution) as opposed to a despotic one.